# Can you get notified about a comment even when you're not @mentioned?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Recently I commented on Gershon Gold's answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/what-shevet-did-a-convert-in-the-midbar-belong-to-if-any/14474#comment26825_14474).
Shortly thereafter (about 5 minutes), I noticed that friendly red notification icon in the top left corner. It was notifying me that Gershon had responded to my comment.

[image: Screenshot from the StackExchange inbox, including notice of a comment, showing the title of the post it's on and the beginning of the comment, which does not include an @mention.]

Just one thing. He [never @mentioned my name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/what-shevet-did-a-convert-in-the-midbar-belong-to-if-any/14474#comment26826_14474). Nor is there the little pen icon next to his post, so it can't be that he mentioned me and then edited it out.

Jeff Atwood has said:

> Rules:
>
> 2.  **Response must include @username that you are referring to,** where "username" is a reasonable match to the user's current display name (as seen in the comments above yours).

But is there another way to get notified by comments, besides for @mentions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) [entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019) says:

> If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if *@name* is forgotten.

Comment: Ah! I was looking for that page, but I couldn't find it. Thanks!